# Ignore NULL values from NetSuite Saved Search Calls

Tags: netsuite

I'm using PHP Toolkit 2013_2 version. Currently I run a transaction typed saved search which returns the responses from NetSuite. 
 But, I get many data with NULL values in the response. 
 So is it possible to either filter only specific items or ignore the NULL values through the NetSuite call itself, so that the time to retrieve response is reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @NONE@ with your filters in NS to prevent null values. In the NS help center you can place a query for searching filter there you can find more info reading the usage.

Here is a small example :

```
var searchFilters= new Array();
searchFilters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('serviceitem', null, 'noneof', '@NONE@');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using 2013_2 toolkit version. Will check with forum on how to use it for this version.